# How to uninstall a Windows Update that seems invisible after installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers, touchpad

I learned the hard way that installing the "Synaptics driver update for Synaptics Composite USB HID Device" on Windows 7 x64 kills the trackpoint and touchpad of my Lenovo USB [SK-8835](https://www.google.com/search?q=SK-8835) USB keyboard.

The uncool thing is that this does

- not list itself in "Installed Updates", so a [guide like here](http://www.howtogeek.com/206271/how-to-roll-back-or-uninstall-a-problematic-windows-update/) or [here](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-uninstall-a-windows-update-that-broke-something-1676817197) does not work.
- not list itself in "Programs and Features" (so it does not show when you run `AppWiz.cpl`)
- not install itself in the "Programs" menu (so there is no uninstaller you can manually run)

What other options do I have to uninstall the particular (optional) Windows Update?

Comment: Do we assume you tried to uninstall it via the "Programs & Features" AKA Add/Remove section?   Is it a driver change or "added" driver and/or software?  because most times you could re-install the driver supplied by the manufacture of the computer (or thier updated version) and the next driver item would replace the MSupdates one. It helps to keep MS updates turned off or disconnect from the web first, while finishing the install of the intended item.  When all else fails it probably used the packaging system, and you could remove it with the DISM stuff.

Comment: System Restore?

Comment: @DavidPostill I was hoping to prevent that. But I might revert to just that. (And thanks for the edit)

Comment: @DavidPostill can you make that an answer, as I resorted to it and it does solve the problem (though it also undoes about everything you did after it, including non-install related things like executable downloads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I to uninstall a Windows Update that seems invisible after installation?

A [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore) will undo all changes to the operating system made after the last restore point.

> Sometimes installing a program or driver can make Windows run slowly or unpredictably. System Restore can return your PC's system files and programs to a time when everything was working fine, potentially preventing hours of troubleshooting headaches. It won't affect your documents, pictures, or other data.

---

#### System Restore will also remove some executables in the user's Downloads directory.

A "system" file is any file in the Windows directory or any file
that has the **"System" file attribute**.

> Specific file types monitored by System Restore is given at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378870.aspx.

Source [What user files does System Restore affect?](https://superuser.com/a/566778/337631) by [Kreemoweet](https://superuser.com/users/99091/kreemoweet):

Comment: I opted for this on the affected machine as very little was changed/installed afterwards. The System Restore will not only undo changes to the operating system, but also remove some (but not all, I've not figured a pattern yet) executables downloaded in the users `Downloads` directory.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers see updated answer.

Comment: that's the thing: none of the downloads had the `System` file attribute set. If memory serves me well, the PSWindowsUpdate and SpeedFan downloads were not affected, but the unzipped UltraDefrag one was in part. Some day I will research this further, but I had only limit time to get that system back to its owner.